# Google apps script to duplicate script in a different folder giving type error when I try to access new sheet id ()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, typeerror

I am trying to run a google apps script that copies the current script to another folder but for some reason [`getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid)  after the copy function [`duplicateactivesheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#duplicateactivesheet) is not allowing me to access the new sheets id.

> TypeError: newSheet.getId is not a function
> copySheetToFolder   @ Code.gs:29

I get a Type error after running:

```
function copySheetToFolder(folderId) {
  // Get the sheet to be copied
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Make a copy of the sheet
  var newSheet = sheet.duplicateActiveSheet();

  // Get the ID of the new sheet
  var newSheetId = newSheet.getId();

  // Get the folder where the sheet will be copied
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  // Add the sheet to the folder
  folder.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetId));
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `a google apps script that copies the current script to another folder`, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood it and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Now, I noticed that you updated your question after I posted an answer. For your updated question, I added one more sample script from your updated script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood it and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Oh, yes @Tanaike I managed to solve the first part then saw my issue was in the second part. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [your provided official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#duplicateactivesheet), `duplicateActiveSheet()` is the method of Class Spreadsheet. But, in your script, `sheet` of `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` is Class Sheet. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(...).duplicateActiveSheet is not a function`.

But, from `a google apps script that copies the current script to another folder`, I thought that you might have wanted to copy the active spreadsheet to the specific folder. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function copySheetToFolder(folderId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId));
}
```

- By this modification, the active Spreadsheet is copied to the specific folder of `folderId`.
- If you want to give a new title of Spreadsheet, please use `DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("new name", DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId))`.

#### Note:

- If you want to use `duplicateActiveSheet()`, please use the following modification.

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var newSheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  ```

#### References:

- [duplicateActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#duplicateactivesheet)
- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [makeCopy(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination)

### Added:

Now, I noticed that you updated your question after I posted an answer. About your new issue of `TypeError: newSheet.getId is not a function`, I think that the reason of your new issue is due to that you are using the sheet ID as the spreadsheet ID. If you want to move the Spreadsheet to the specific folder after you copied the active sheet, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function copySheetToFolder(folderId) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var ssId = sheet.getId();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).moveTo(folder);
}
```

- From your showing script, in this modification, the active sheet is copied and the active Spreasheet is moved to the specific folder.
- In the current stage, `addFile` of Class Folder has been deprecated. Please be careful about this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addfilechild) In this modification, `moveTo` is used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike I have learned so much about gsheets from you. Your work is amazing and I really appreciate it.